# PayPal IPN - Redirect page before opened paypal site

Tags: javascript, php, html, security, paypal

could someone please help me to fix the paypal forms issue, once click submit, need to redirect to paypal.php then go to paypal site for payment. The issue is when doing this, the payments values in paypel site is empty and not showing product name and price.

Thank you in advance!

**index.php**

```js
<?
$products = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `id` > '0' ORDER BY `price` ASC");
for($j=1; $product = $products->fetch_assoc(); $j++){
?>       
<?
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   redirect_to('functions/paypal/paypal.php');
  }
?>
  <form method="post">
                     <tr style="border-bottom:1px solid #f2f3f6;">
                         <td><?=$product['name'];?></td>
                            <td><?=$product['price'];?></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" value="Buy" name="submit" /></td>
                        </tr>
  </form>
<?}?>
```

**paypal.php forms**

```js
<?
require('functions/db.php');
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>redirect to paypal service..</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 setTimeout('document.formpaypal.submit()',1000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="formpaypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?=$sites['paypal']?>">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?=$product['name'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?=$data['id'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?=$product['price'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="index.php?success">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="index.php?cancel">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="funtions/paypal/ipn.php">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to add the data from index.php to the paypal.php page?

Comment: @BlakeConnally - Yes, I want to show the product in index.php and when buyer click submit, they redirected to paypal.php to take forms inputs and then redirect to paypal.com for payment. Please any help, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing in paypal.php should just be done in index.php.  You can build out the payment form directly in index and when they click submit from there it would send them directly to PayPal.  No need for a "middle man" script.

Comment: Yes, I know it can be made directly in index.php, but I need to use two files, one to show products price,name and the other for for paypal inputs forms. Could you please help me, because I already saw that on many websites. Thank you so much!

Comment: If it's getting redirected to PayPal but the data isn't getting there, that means the form must not be getting populated the way you think.  Remove the auto-submit and let the page load so you can view source and see if the form data is populated correctly.

Comment: When I delete this "setTimeout('document.paypalform.submit()',1000);" code on paypal.php, and I try to inspect element, I found that all values of item_name, amount, item_number is empty. Is there is way to keep values when redirect from index.php to paypal.php, perhaps with session?...Please any advice, I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: If you insist on using the "middle-man script" then yes, I would recommend going with session data to pass it around as necessary.  Typically would what you're doing would make more sense if you're working with APIs instead of working with standard HTML forms.  There really is no reason to go through that extra page like you're trying to do with the HTML form.  Just build the form dynamically in the index page and you'd be done.

Comment: Could you please write me how to do it with session or APIs if you don't mind? I'm really new and don't understand how to do it. Thank you so much dear Andrew for your time and help.